# How to avoid duplicate code in the activity and fragment?

Tags: android, code-duplication

When an activity is launched, the condition is checked in it, if the condition is true, the `openNewActivity` method is called and the current activity ends. But if the condition is false, then a transition is made to the fragment, inside which this condition can become true and then you need to call the `openNewActivity` method, which is defined in the activity. I do not want to duplicate this method in the fragment, how to properly implement a call to this method from the fragment? What are the best practices in such cases?

Comment: Move it to a separate class?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad I can be wrong, but it seems to me a very appropriate solution to carry this method into a separate class
I am considering the option to call In fragment ((MyActivity) getActivity()). CallMethod(), but I don’t know if this is a good way

Comment: You could do that too, but then it's about exposing activity methods to another class. Personally, I would create a separate class, put the method in there and then access it in your project. Non-UI logic generally should be taken to a separate class

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Why is opening a new activity a non-ui logic?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant about the condition, opening a new activity is not a non-UI thread, in fact, only activity should handle opening another activity. You could use `interfaces` to solve the problem. Fragment tells the activity to open the new activity. Let me write an example.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad What is the advantage of the interface over ((My Activity) getActivity()).CallMethod() in this case?

Comment: Only an activity should be able to start another activity, asking the fragment to start an activity is not really 'neat'. You can write whatever code you want and it will work, but at the end of the day writing code is more than just about making something work. Interface is a clean OOP way to handle tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Activity**

```
class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {

     override fun onSomethingDone() { //This function gets called when the condition is true
        openNewActivity()
     }


     override fun onAttachFragment(fragment: Fragment) { //A fragment MUST never know it's an activity, so we exposed fragment interface member to easily initialize it whenever the fragment is attached to the activity.
         when (fragment) {
              is MyFragment -> fragment.myInterface = this
            }

      }

     override fun onCreate() {
          super.onCreate()
      }


    private fun openNewActivity() {
        //opens a new activity    
    }

}
```

**Interface**

```
interface MyInterface {
     fun onSomethingDone()
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
   var myInterface: MyInterface? = null


 override fun onCreate() {
     if (somethingIsTrue)
         myInterface.onSomethingDone() //condition is true, call the interface method to inform the activity that the condition is true and the new activity should be opened.
   }

}
```

Create an interface. Initialize the fragment's interface in the activity's `onAttachFragment` for the reason mentioned in the code. This way, the function for starting a new activity is defined only in the activity and does not need to be duplicated in the fragment.

Comment: This way seems to me very cumbersome, but if calling the activity method from fragment is a bad decision, then I will do as you say. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will get used it to it, sometimes a 'cumbersome' code has to be written to respect a clean software design